# How to check for Certain Properties in Docker Images

Tags: docker

I have a set of Docker base images within my organization. I have one per technology stack (Java or Python for example). I can also build these base images for a specific version of Java and push it to the artifactory.

We will then have different projects who will use these base images and construc their Dockerfile. We now want to somehow ensure during the build process of those projects that they did infact use the base image that I created in their Dockerfile!

For example., if the image that I created for Java on Alipine is called

```
java-8-alpine-3
```

Then the project that would need a Java runtime should have this as their first line:

```
FROM java-8-alipne-3
```

How do I ensure that this is the case? In other words, how can I inspect the images to check for usage of such properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well for a particular image you can use century link image which will reverse engineer the docker image

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
centurylink/dockerfile-from-image <IMAGE_TAG_OR_ID>
```

[click here for more info](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image)

unfortunately century link image use docker tree command which is depreciated so the other solution is to use this

```
docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
nate/dockviz images -t
```

it will display all the layers you can go through inspecting all the layers then .

Comment: What is the $INSTANCE_ID? Is is the name of the Image that I wish to inspect?

Comment: Is the .Config.Image flag corresponds to the FROM tag with which I can check if my base image is used?

Comment: well instance_id is the name of the docker instance that is running

Comment: I want to do the check on the Docker Image and not on the running container instance

Comment: Nope! That is not what I want! I want to be able to do that on the static image and not on the running container!

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding can you try this: docker image inspect [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Comment: Docker image inspect seems also not what I want! I get a JSON back, but from the JSON I cannot say what its FROM command is

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get `FROM` line just having the image.

You can use `docker history --no-trunc image_name` to get the history of an image, but you can't get `FROM` line.

Take a look to this thread on Docker forum for further information: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-view-the-dockerfile-in-an-image/5687/3

Comment: No! This is not what I want! I think it is clear that I want to be able to identify the parent image in the Dockerfile!

Comment: That's NOT possible, as is stated in the link that I put in my answer.

Comment: see my updated answer, as the century link image is broken, a fixed one exists

Answer (score -1):

if you just need to know the `FROM xxx` line used to build your images, just do

`docker history --no-trunc my_image`

and you will get that information

The doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/

Edit:

https://hub.docker.com/r/dduvnjak/dockerfile-from-image/

is a fixed version of

https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image/issues/14

which no longer works

for example

`$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  dduvnjak/dockerfile-from-image  k3ck3c/nethogs
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk add wget&& wget --no-check-certificate -c http://github.com/raboof/nethogs/archive/v0.8.1.tar.gz && tar zvxf v0.8.1.tar.gz && cd ./nethogs-0.8.1/ && echo "export ARCH=x86" >> Makefile && apk add sudo linux-headers ncurses-dev libpcap-dev make g++&& echo "@testing http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories && apk update && apk add libpcap libstdc++ libgcc nethogs@testing&& make && sudo make install&& apk del sudo g++ make linux-headers ncurses-dev libpcap-dev libpcap libgcc libstdc++ && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* ./nethogs-0.8.1/`

shows the

`FROM`

line correctly

or just

`$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  dduvnjak/dockerfile-from-image  k3ck3c/nethogs | grep FROM
FROM alpine:latest`

Comment: Actually you can't get `FROM xxx` line with `docker history --no-trunc my_image`

Comment: https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image used to show this, but it is broken at the moment, and it does nearly the same things, see the code

Comment: the code https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image/blob/master/dockerfile-from-image.rb